# Asynchronous data fetching in Clickhouse does not work

Tags: python, python-asyncio, aiohttp, clickhouse

```
from datetime import datetime

import asyncio
from aiohttp import ClientSession
from aiochclient import ChClient


async def some_query(client, sql):
     print(f"Start {i} - {datetime.now()}")      
     all_rows = await client.fetch(sql, json=True)
     print(f"End {i}")
        
     return all_rows

async def compete():
    tasks = []
    async with ClientSession() as session:
        my_client = ChClient(session, url=f'http://{USER}:{PWD}@{HOST}:{PORT}/', 
                             database=DB)
        for i in range(1, 3):
            task = asyncio.create_task(self.some_query(my_client, i, "SELECT * FROM table"))
            tasks.append(task)
            
        await asyncio.gather(*tasks)

asyncio.run(compete())
```

The code works, but when the request comes to the database, it is executed there synchronously.
For example, 3 requests are completed in 180 seconds and there is no difference whether it happens synchronously or asynchronously.
Am I right in thinking that if you run the code asynchronously, then 3 requests should be completed in about 60 seconds?

Comment: You should not use `asyncio.gather` after `asyncio.create_task` as it creates task for each coroutine provided with parameters. Eighter keep `asyncio.create_task(self.some_query(my_client, i, "SELECT * FROM table"))` or append `self.some_query(my_client, i, "SELECT * FROM table")` in your `tasks`